# Is there a way to edit individual instances of a class in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a calendar in CSS, and I want to have a single event continually span the days that the event is scheduled for instead of being individually broken up. I'm fluent in CSS but I'm struggling to figure out how to edit this so that, for example, "Event #1" doesn't have any breaks between days, but is instead one, continuous black line until the last day where it is complete.

[image]

This is what I'm trying to accomplish.
[image]

My current code looks like this and this is a live link to the [website](http://maryama.sg-host.com/) (it's the second section of the site)

````
<table class="spiffy calendar-table bigcal spiffy-weekly">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="calendar-heading">
            <td colspan="7" class="calendar-date-switcher">
                <table class="calendar-heading-tbl">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="calendar-prev"><a rel="nofollow" onclick="sessionStorage.scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();" href="/?preview_id=17&amp;preview_nonce=f0919fcc84&amp;_thumbnail_id=-1&amp;preview=true&amp;daynum=06&amp;month=dec&amp;yr=2020">&lt;</a>
                            </td>

                            <td class="calendar-month">December 2020</td>
                            <td class="calendar-next"><a rel="nofollow" onclick="sessionStorage.scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();" href="/?preview_id=17&amp;preview_nonce=f0919fcc84&amp;_thumbnail_id=-1&amp;preview=true&amp;daynum=14&amp;month=dec&amp;yr=2020">&gt;</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="weekday-titles">
            <td class="normal-day-heading">Monday</td>
            <td class="normal-day-heading">Tuesday</td>
            <td class="normal-day-heading">Wednesday</td>
            <td class="normal-day-heading">Thursday</td>
            <td class="normal-day-heading">Friday</td>
            <td class="weekend-heading">Saturday</td>
            <td class="weekend-heading">Sunday</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="spiffy-day-07  no-events day-with-date"><span class="day-number">07</span><span class="event"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="spiffy-day-08  no-events day-with-date"><span class="day-number">08</span><span class="event"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="spiffy-day-09  day-with-date"><span class="day-number">09</span><span class="event"><span class="calnk category_1 category-bg"><span onclick="" class="calnk-link" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#000000;"><span class="calnk-box"><a href="https://link.com" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#000000;" target="_blank"><span class="spiffy-title">Event #1</span>
                </a><span class="spiffy-popup" style="color:#000000;"><a href="https://link.com" target="_blank"><span class="event-title" style="color:#000000;">Event #1</span><span class="event-title-break"></span><span class="ca-desc-p">Event description</span>
                </a><span class="ca-location-p">Event location</span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="spiffy-day-10  day-with-date"><span class="day-number">10</span><span class="event"><span class="calnk category_1 category-bg"><span onclick="" class="calnk-link" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#000000;"><span class="calnk-box"><a href="https://link.com" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#000000;" target="_blank"><span class="spiffy-title">Event #1</span>
                </a><span class="spiffy-popup" style="color:#000000;"><a href="https://link.com" target="_blank"><span class="event-title" style="color:#000000;">Event #1</span><span class="event-title-break"></span><span class="ca-desc-p">Event description</span>
                </a><span class="ca-location-p">Event location</span>

                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                <span class="calnk category_2 category-bg"><span onclick="" class="calnk-link" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#6d6d6d;"><span class="calnk-box"><span class="spiffy-title">Tornament</span><span class="spiffy-popup" style="color:#6d6d6d;"><span class="event-title" style="color:#6d6d6d;">Tornament</span>
                <span class="event-title-break"></span><span class="ca-desc-p">Tournament description</span>
                <span class="ca-location-p">Tournament description</span>

                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="spiffy-day-11  day-with-date"><span class="day-number">11</span><span class="event"><span class="calnk category_1 category-bg"><span onclick="" class="calnk-link" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#000000;"><span class="calnk-box"><a href="https://link.com" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#000000;" target="_blank"><span class="spiffy-title">Event #1</span>
                </a><span class="spiffy-popup" style="color:#000000;"><a href="https://link.com" target="_blank"><span class="event-title" style="color:#000000;">Event #1</span><span class="event-title-break"></span><span class="ca-desc-p">Event description</span>
                </a><span class="ca-location-p">Event location</span>

                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                <span class="calnk category_2 category-bg"><span onclick="" class="calnk-link" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#6d6d6d;"><span class="calnk-box"><span class="spiffy-title">Tornament</span><span class="spiffy-popup" style="color:#6d6d6d;"><span class="event-title" style="color:#6d6d6d;">Tornament</span>
                <span class="event-title-break"></span><span class="ca-desc-p">Tournament description</span>
                <span class="ca-location-p">Tournament description</span>

                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="spiffy-day-12  weekend day-with-date"><span class="day-number weekend">12</span><span class="event"><span class="calnk category_1 category-bg"><span onclick="" class="calnk-link" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#000000;"><span class="calnk-box"><a href="https://link.com" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#000000;" target="_blank"><span class="spiffy-title">Event #1</span>
                </a><span class="spiffy-popup" style="color:#000000;"><a href="https://link.com" target="_blank"><span class="event-title" style="color:#000000;">Event #1</span><span class="event-title-break"></span><span class="ca-desc-p">Event description</span>
                </a><span class="ca-location-p">Event location</span>

                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                <span class="calnk category_2 category-bg"><span onclick="" class="calnk-link" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#6d6d6d;"><span class="calnk-box"><span class="spiffy-title">Tornament</span><span class="spiffy-popup" style="color:#6d6d6d;"><span class="event-title" style="color:#6d6d6d;">Tornament</span>
                <span class="event-title-break"></span><span class="ca-desc-p">Tournament description</span>
                <span class="ca-location-p">Tournament description</span>

                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="spiffy-day-13 current-day weekend day-with-date"><span class="day-number weekend">13</span><span class="event"><span class="calnk category_1 category-bg"><span onclick="" class="calnk-link" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#000000;"><span class="calnk-box"><a href="https://link.com" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#000000;" target="_blank"><span class="spiffy-title">Event #1</span>
                </a><span class="spiffy-popup" style="color:#000000;"><a href="https://link.com" target="_blank"><span class="event-title" style="color:#000000;">Event #1</span><span class="event-title-break"></span><span class="ca-desc-p">Event description</span>
                </a><span class="ca-location-p">Event location</span>

                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                <span class="calnk category_2 category-bg"><span onclick="" class="calnk-link" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#6d6d6d;"><span class="calnk-box"><span class="spiffy-title">Tornament</span><span class="spiffy-popup" style="color:#6d6d6d;"><span class="event-title" style="color:#6d6d6d;">Tornament</span>
                <span class="event-title-break"></span><span class="ca-desc-p">Tournament description</span>
                <span class="ca-location-p">Tournament description</span>

                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                <span class="calnk category_3 category-bg"><span onclick="" class="calnk-link" style="color: #FFFFFF; background:#dd3333;"><span class="calnk-box"><span class="spiffy-title">Show #1</span><span class="spiffy-popup" style="color:#dd3333;"><span class="event-title" style="color:#dd3333;">Show #1</span>
                <span class="event-title-break"></span>

                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>```
````

Comment: I did it in css. Is it so necessary? - https://ibb.co/dM6Sh85

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov how'd ya do that!? yes, it's necessary from a UX perspective

Comment: Ok. Now I will write a detailed answer.

Comment: Can you create a class for this `tr` tag now? - (https://ibb.co/kDDx4xC) Otherwise, when referring to tags, there will be a very long selector.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yes, i can add it via javascript

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov actually nevermind, no i can't. long selectors are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

In order to get the effect of a solid line of events, you need to add this selector:

```
.wpb_wrapper table tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:not(.no-events) .calnk.category_1 {
    margin-left: -3px;
    margin-right: -3px;
}
```

`margin-left` and `margin-right` will expand the boxes to the desired width, where 3 pixels will be enough for me.

This selector sets the specified rules for all `.calnk.category_1`, taking into account the exception of the `.no-events` class, the `td` tag.

If you need to make a solid stripe effect for all lines, then exclude the `.category_1` class from the selector. It should look like this:

```
.wpb_wrapper table tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:not(.no-events) .calnk { ... }
```

At this stage, the basis of the problem is solved. But it will also require adjustments to the first and last block. This can be done using pseudo-classes `first-of-type` and `last-of-type`. But with this, I think you can easily handle :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of selecting the nth element by class. You will have to use something like

```
.weekParent div:first-of-type{}
.weekParent div:last-of-type{}
```

or

```
.weekParent div:nth-of-type(2){}
```